# Google Calendar API DoS prevention

Tags: google-calendar-api

[It appears](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?fid=3024e478823deabc000486d18d09efa5&hl=en) that the Google calendar API effectively locks you out if you create and delete a few (less than 10) calendars within a short space of time.

This has made it basically impossible for me to test my app, because it creates/deletes a calendar for each user that is added/removed from the app. Currently, I'm "working around" this issue by creating a new Google account each time I get locked out of the Calendar API. Clearly, this solution is less than satisfactory.

Is there any way I can avoid this over-zealous DoS prevention?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Is the allowed throttling rate published (i.e. what constitutes a "short space of time")? Also, is your application running on a single server, or are there multiple servers making requests to Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

If your application doesn't require an instantaneous call out to the Google API, your code can queue the actions and throttle the calls to `x` calls over `y` seconds.  Not an ideal solution but it would reduce the likelihood of hitting the quota limit.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just "reset" (i.e. delete all entries) the test calendars instead of re-creating them every time?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a localized version of the calendar that you either have the user save (upload to Google) with a button click or as an event (ie. closing the program, every x minutes).  Store all the data locally, and only upload to Google as needed.  I don't know how neccessary it is that the data be available immediately, but if your app can handle some delay, then this may work for you.